# CNN Data Incorrect Input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a lip-reading CNN on facial images. Each image is 64 by 64 pixels which are flattened to a 1D array of size 4096 in a Pandas data frame. I have encoded the labels to numbers. Here is my training data:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, labels, random_state = 42, test_size = 0.2, stratify = labels)
X_train = tf.reshape(X_train, (-1, 8113, 4096, 1))
X_test = tf.reshape(X_test, (-1, 2029, 4096, 1))
y_train = tf.reshape(y_train, (1, 8113, 1))
y_test = tf.reshape(y_test, (1, 2029, 1))
```

Which gives me output shapes of:

```
(1, 8113, 4096, 1)
(1, 2029, 4096, 1)
(1, 8113, 1)
(1, 2029, 1)
```

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size=3, activation ='relu',strides = 2, padding = 'valid', input_shape= (8113, 4096, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters= 128, kernel_size=3, activation ='relu',strides = 2, padding = 'valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.9))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(39)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs = 30, batch_size = 256, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), shuffle = True)
```

When I run the model, I get this error:

```
    ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 8113 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze)' with input shapes: [?,8113].
```

Is there something wrong with my loss function and should i be using categorical_cross_entropy instead of sparse? Or is my data input shapes for train and test wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do run a CNN on flattend images? If so, you need to use Conv1D not Conv2D also. That first dimension of 1, that's not needed the 8113 should be the first dimension.

Comment: Will Conv2d give me a better accuracy?

Comment: It probably will. When you flatten images you lose lot of spatial information

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I will try not to flatten my data and see how it does. What would be the x-train and y-train input shapes for a Conv2d model?

Comment: your train data would be `8113x64x64x1` shaped

Comment: Thank you! Would this apply for both X-train and Y-train?